# How to fetch Instagram feed of a non-business account on website with Instagram Graph API?

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Due to Instagram Platform API deprecation, I want to fetch my Instagram feed which is a non-business account on my PHP based website with the Instagram Graph API.

Can someone help me, how I can work with Instagram Graph API to fetch my feed like a gallery?

Answer (score 0):

You can only pull your Instagram feed if it is a business account with Instagram graph API, You cannot pull anyother user's feed business or non-business.

Comment: Thanks krisrak, do you have any running example help links where I can see the fetching of instagram feed through graph API?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [the Business Discovery API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery/):

`curl -i -X GET  "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/17841405309211844?fields=business_discovery.username(bluebottle){followers_count,media_count,media{comments_count,like_count}}&access_token={access-token}"`